# passing value of a variable from one function to onListItemClick() in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass the value of `path` from a function to `onListItemClick()` in the same class. But I am unable to do that. Please see the following sample code -

```
public void insert(String path) //I want to pass this path variable to onListItemClick().
{
  setListAdapter(adapter);
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  // ListView Clicked item index
   int itemPosition     = position;

  // ListView Clicked item value
   String  itemValue    = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

 //  content.setText("Click : \n  Position :"+itemPosition+"  \n  ListItem : " +itemValue);
   info.insert(path,itemValue); //Here I am using the path variable.


}
```

Please help me, as I am a newbie to android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Till now, I did not pass the value, because I am unable to understand, how to do that task.

Comment: If it's in the same class, set an instance field with the value that `path` would have and access it from `onListItemClick`.

Comment: Use Bundle Class To parse The Value

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I am sorry that I could not understand how to do it. If you don't mind, can you please demonstrate it as an answer please?

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, how to do it?

Comment: i thing u have String object and u wnat to use the in Secand Class    m i right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the interface you're implementing but by using instance fields across instance methods, you can solve this problem

```
public class Main {
    private String tempPath;

    public void insert(String path) {       
        this.tempPath = path;
        onListItemClick(null, null, 0, 0);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(Object l, Object v, int position, long id) { // just for show, should be your actual method
        System.out.println(tempPath); // do some null check, obviously
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.insert("Path to enlightenment.");
    }
}
```